# How to popmodal a page inside a static method in Xamarin forms?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am working with a login to my app currently and right now I am on the iOS part.

I have created a custom renderer looking like this:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(TwitterLogin), typeof(TwitterLogin_iOS))]
```

When my auth is completed in the iOS-renderer:

```
auth.Completed += (object sender, AuthenticatorCompletedEventArgs ee) => 
{
    TwitterLogin.SuccessfulLoginAction.Invoke();
}
```

I have created a function looking like this on my TwitterLogin page in my shared code that runs when the login is complete:

```
public static Action SuccessfulLoginAction
    {
        get
        {
            return new Action(async () =>
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("login is complete!");
            });
        }
    }
```

What I want to happen once the user has logged in is for the page to popmodalasync, (it was previously pushmodalasync'd to its current page, TwitterLogin-page) and what I am trying to do is add the method inside the SuccessfulLoginAction-action:

```
await Navigation.PopModalAsync ();
```

But as SuccessfulLoginAction is a static method I cannot reach `Navigation`.

If I do this:

```
 auth.Completed += (object sender, AuthenticatorCompletedEventArgs ee) => 
{
    TwitterLogin.SuccessfulLoginAction.Invoke();
    TwitterLogin log = new TwitterLogin();
    log.popPage();
}
```

and have the function like this on the twitterlogin page:

```
public async void popPage ()
    {
        await Navigation.PopModalAsync();
    }
```

I get the crash `Index was out of range. Must be a non-negative and less than size of the collection` Strange to me because I start from another page with this code: `await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new TwitterLogin());`

I also tried with `MessagingCenter`but as I cannot use `this`inside a static method I am not 100 % sure on how to make it work, when I use "null" I get a crash obviously:

```
return new Action(async () =>
{
MessagingCenter.Send<TwitterLogin>(null, "popPage");
}

public TwitterLogin()
{
    MessagingCenter.Subscribe<TwitterLogin>(null, "popPage", async (sender) => {
        await Navigation.PopModalAsync();
    });
}
```

Any idea on how I can adjust the code/alternative method so I can popmodal the current page?

Comment: Why not do it before or after your `TwitterLogin.SuccessfulLoginAction.Invoke();` call?

Comment: How would that look you mean?

Comment: No, I mean isn't that a solution? Adding it in the call you do on the `auth.Completed +=` line.

Comment: Ah you mean adding it inside that function in my iOS page. When I enter "Navigation" I can't find it though. I can find NavigationPage however but nothing after it if I keep searching.

Comment: This looks remarkably like what I was doing when messing with the Xamarin Auth project.  If you are attempting the same sort of thing, I would suggest that you look down the "Dependency Service" route rather than the custom renderer. It made a lot more sense doing it that way for me.

Comment: Ended up solving it with a event handler and this code snippet `Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PopAsync();`

Answer (score 0):

Ended up solving it with this code:

```
TwitterLogin log = new TwitterLogin();

auth.Completed += (object sender, AuthenticatorCompletedEventArgs ee) => 
{
   log.OnButtonClicked();
}
```

And on the page:

```
public event EventHandler ButtonClicked;

public async void OnButtonClicked()
{
    await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PopAsync();
}
```